# Error when building bfilter

Tags: compiling

I tried to build [bfilter](http://bfilter.sourceforge.net/) from source, but get the following error:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4'
Making all in binreloc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/binreloc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/binreloc'
Making all in foundation
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/foundation'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/foundation'
Making all in boost
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost'
Making all in libs
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost/libs'
Making all in regex
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost/libs/regex'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost/libs/regex'
Making all in program_options
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost/libs/program_options'
/bin/bash ../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../..  -I../../.. -I../../../boost -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION -DNDEBUG  -Os -Wall -Wno-unused -pthread -MT config_file.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/config_file.Tpo -c -o config_file.lo `test -f 'src/config_file.cpp' || echo './'`src/config_file.cpp
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../.. -I../../../boost -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION -DNDEBUG -Os -Wall -Wno-unused -pthread -MT config_file.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/config_file.Tpo -c src/config_file.cpp -o config_file.o
In file included from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:23:0,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:34,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/eof_iterator.hpp:9,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp:17,
                 from src/config_file.cpp:10:
../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply_wrap.hpp:81:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply_wrap.hpp:173:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/bind.hpp:27:0,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/lambda.hpp:18,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:25,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:34,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/eof_iterator.hpp:9,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp:17,
                 from src/config_file.cpp:10:
../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply_wrap.hpp:81:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply_wrap.hpp:173:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/lambda.hpp:18:0,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:25,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:34,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/eof_iterator.hpp:9,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp:17,
                 from src/config_file.cpp:10:
../../../boost/boost/mpl/bind.hpp:364:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
../../../boost/boost/mpl/bind.hpp:531:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/lambda.hpp:22:0,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:25,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:34,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/eof_iterator.hpp:9,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp:17,
                 from src/config_file.cpp:10:
../../../boost/boost/mpl/aux_/full_lambda.hpp:230:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from ../../../boost/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:34:0,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/eof_iterator.hpp:9,
                 from ../../../boost/boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp:17,
                 from src/config_file.cpp:10:
../../../boost/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:138:31: error: missing binary operator before token "("
make[4]: *** [config_file.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost/libs/program_options'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost/libs'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4/boost'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/Downloads/bfilter-1.1.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What versions of G++, Boost and ACE do you have?

Comment: `g++`: 4:4.5.2-1ubuntu3, `libace`: 5.7.7-4ubuntu1, `libboost-1.42-dev`: 1.42.0-4ubuntu2

Answer (score 2):

There is problem in gcc, which cannot have MACRO() in the `#elif` condition in header structure.

See [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6631) link with possible workaround and [discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/228802) about this problem.

Comment: Thanks. Please could you provide more details what to do in my situation? Would it be possible to just replace gcc or boost locally for making bfilter somehow? (I am using ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: You can change `#elif` to `#else #if`, as you can see in the first link I provided... It is hard to recognize, but please, check differences between original file and corrected file in the post, which is started by 'Modifying file.h to be the following fixes the problem for me'.